# Loop through a vector and copy the elements into a C array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

The project I am working on requires a bunch of translation from C++ concepts to C.  In this use case, the caller is responsible for managing the memory buffer.  He then calls the function and provides the array of type double and the amount of memory he allocated.  Then the function fills his array buffer with all the doubles in the vector.  This is my first shot at the function, but I am not sure if it is correct.  Since I am not too familiar with C, I am sure there are mistakes.  Am I doing this right?  And how about adding the null terminating `\0` at the end?

```
void getMoments(uint32_t & bufferSize,
                double * moments)
{
  if ( bufferSize < (vec.size() * sizeof(double)) + 1 )
  {
    // set error: bufferSize is not large enough to copy elements of vector.
  }

  typedef std::vector<double>::const_iterator it_type;

  for (it_type it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) 
  {
    double e = *it;
    std::memcpy(moments, &e, sizeof(double));
  }

  // How do I add the null terminating \0?
}
```

By the way, the bufferSize is passed by reference because FORTRAN is one client and the language requires everything be passed by reference.

What confuses me about C arrays is the notion (or lack of notion) of a *pointer*.  How do we know where we are at in the C array?  In other words, every time I call memcpy should it write starting at the beginning of the array, thus overwriting my previously written bytes?

Comment: pointers in C are not much different than in C++. you should perhaps first reading up on these before you try that.

Comment: Huh? C? This is C++. Is this the function you are going to translate to C or your attempt at doing that? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: The function is part of a C API, but I am free to use C++ in the definition.  The only requirement is that the function copies the vector into the C style array.

Comment: There is nothing about this code that will work in C, neither in the function declaration nor definition: there is nothing in C called references, so `uint32_t &` isn't going to compile.

Comment: The point is that it must support a C client, not that it be written in C.  I should have said it is a C binding.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues wrote detailed answer. think it will help you to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer can be used as an output iterator:

```
if (bufferSize < vec.size() * sizeof(double))
{
  // error: buffer too small
  return;
}

std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), moments);
```

Note: if you are passing a pointer to double, I would express the buffer/array size in terms of doubles as well, rather than chars (bytes).

Comment: Interesting!  Can you explain why `double` can be used as an OutputIterator?

Comment: @jakeliquorblues It is a pointer to double. It can be de-referenced, the thing it points to can be assigned to, and it can be incremented/decremented . A pointer to an element of an array *is* an iterator.

Comment: Iterators are defined by concepts rather than base classes. These concepts describe a number of operations the type should support. Any type supporting the operations required by the "output iterator" concept can thus be used as an output iterator. You can find these requirements here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator

You will notice that a non-const pointer satisfies these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would ever need to null terminate array of doubles, so I removed it.

Full code:

```
void getMoments(uint32_t & bufferSize, double * moments)
{
    if ( bufferSize < (vec.size() * sizeof(double)) )
    {
        // set error: bufferSize is not large enough to copy elements of vector.
    }

    typedef std::vector<double>::const_iterator it_type;

    for (it_type it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) 
    {
        *moments++ = *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes!  A null terminating `\0` is for C strings!  Not double arrays.  My lack of fundamentals are showing :(

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
...

int getMoments(uint32_t* bufferSize,
                double * moments)
{
    std::vector<double> vec = ...
    if (*bufferSize/sizeof(double) < vec.size())
        return -1;
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), moments);
    return 0;
}
```

See also [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

**Note:** a "reference" is not available in C. Thus, your C API must pass parameter *bufferSize* as pointer.